# Does the limit exist for the following function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How can we justify that the limit does/does not exist for this function?
http://uploadpie.com/7VL6o

My attempt is that:

If y=0 , we have lim = 0

if x=0 , we have lim = 0

but does that mean the limit actualy exist at 0?

My book uses another method which is set y=x so we get:
lim(x,x)->(0,0) which also equals 0...

Is this enough of a proof that the limit exists at zero?

Comment: Hint: consider the path $x = y^2$

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated, along $y=0$ the limit is $0$.

Along $x = y^2$, $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} = \frac{y^4}{y^4 + y^4} \to \frac{1}{2}$, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks so much! In this case, would I write the notation as 
"lim(y^2,y) -> (0,0)" ?

Also how would one normally figure that x=y^2 , is it more of a general observation from the equation?

Comment: Letting $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2 + y^4}$, we write $\lim_{x,y \to 0} f(y^2, y)$.